# Python3.x Using easyGUI with magic number game

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

```
import random, easygui as eg

 def main(low=1, high=100):
  """Guess My Number

The computer picks a random number between low and high
The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
the player know if the guess is too high, too low
or right on the money

"""
print("Welcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between {} and {}.".format(low, high))
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.")

the_number = random.randint(low, high)
tries = 0

while True:
    guess = ask_number("Enter your guess:", low, high)
    if guess == the_number:
        print("You're right on the money!")
        break
    elif guess > the_number:
        print("Too high!")
    else:
        print("Too low!")
    tries += 1

print("You guessed it! The number was {}.".format(the_number))
print("And it only took you {} tries!".format(tries))
input("Press the enter key to exit.")

def ask_number(question, low, high):
"""Get the user to input a number in the appropriate range."""
while True:
    try:
        response = int(input(question))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Not an integer")
    else:
        if response in range(low, high+1):
            return response
        print ("Out of range")

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

hey guys im trying to get the following code to work within a GUI with easyGUI but im not so sure how to do it im trying to get input and return text or other gui would work to i open to suggestions

Comment: i didn't indent it properly when i posted it i thought it was right
sorry Malik

Comment: Where is your `easygui` code? All I see is basic IO.

Comment: havent done anything not to sure how it works im using easy gui v0.96

Comment: Well as the OP you need to show some prior effort on SO. Can you use `tkinter` as well?

Comment: no sorry im a beginner

Comment: Can I use `tkinter` instead of `easygui`?

Comment: @Gilamesh Made it for `tkinter` are you using Python 3 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

################################################################################
# Application ##################################################################
################################################################################

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self); self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(640, 480))

        self.button = Button(text = 'Check', command = self.checknum)
        self.button.place_configure(x = 170, y = 260, width = 300)

        self.value = IntVar(); self.number = Entry(textvariable = self.value)
        self.number.place_configure(x = 170, y = 220, width = 300)

        self.store = randint(1, 100)
        self.state, self.tries = 1, 0

        self.label_1 = Label(text = 'Tries: {}'.format(self.tries))
        self.label_1.place_configure(x = 10, y = 10) # place label

        self.label_2 = Label(text = 'Messages: ')
        self.label_2.place_configure(x = 10, y = 40)

        self.mainloop()


    def checknum(self):
        if self.state:
            if self.value.get() > self.store:
                self.tries += 1
                self.label_1.configure(text = 'Tries: {}'.format(self.tries))
                self.label_2.configure(text = 'Messages: {}'.format('Lower'))

            if self.value.get() < self.store:
                self.tries += 1
                self.label_1.configure(text = 'Tries: {}'.format(self.tries))
                self.label_2.configure(text = 'Messages: {}'.format('Higher'))

            if self.value.get() == self.store:
                self.tries += 1; self.state = 0
                self.label_1.configure(text = 'Tries: {}'.format(self.tries))
                self.label_2.configure(text = 'Messages: {}'.format('You won'))

################################################################################
# Run ##########################################################################
################################################################################

app = Application()

################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in 0
builtins.ImportError: No module named Tkinter
so close

Comment: Did you change `Tkinter` to `tkinter`? You are probably on Python 3, no?

Comment: Mail could we corrosponde via email i need some help with tkinter